# Prevent non-const object being used after container takes copy

Tags: c++

I have a function which modifies an object and then a container takes a copy and stores:

```
void modifyObjectAndStore(Obj& obj)
{
    obj.a = 5;
    obj.b = 8;
    // there's state set here which isn't possible to set in the caller

    _container.takeCopy(obj);

   // From this point on obj should not be modified/used directly
}
```

Once the container takes a copy and stores it, `obj` should not be used directly.

What is the best way to ensure this, or failing that, make the intent clear?

Comment: Do you mean `not used` for the rest of this function, or do you mean ever again?

Comment: `Obj&& obj`? This lets you move into the container instead of copying, and signals that the argument shouldn't be used after the call.

Comment: seems to be xy problem. the original object has no relation to the stored copy after storing it! why do u want to do that. consider moing the original object.

Comment: @quamrana I want to stop someone changing the state of the object after it has been stored because the cached copy (in the container) won't contain those changes when they read it later.

Comment: , hence move the original object to ur container and no one can change the object in the container.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat i was thinking that, just wasn't sure if i needed a unique_ptr. Is this going to guarantee the object cannot be changed after, or it just signals the code's intention reading it? Would accessing obj later cause a compiler error?

Comment: The only things that can be done to an object after moving it are:  re-assignment to a new object, or destruction, or "operations without preconditions", or for some standard C++ object a few other limited things (for example, std::vector and std::unique_ptr provide a few more guarantees).  It's *undefined behavior* to do anything else with the *valid-but-unspecified-state* object.  If you want **stronger** guarantees for using an object after such a point, you'd have to add in additional invariant checking and assert or std::terminate or throw as desired.

Comment: @Eljay ah okay but there's nothing I can do to get the compiler to throw an error? Sounds like a possible compiler suggestion, as clearly after the move the object shouldn't be changed.

Comment: It's a good suggestion, but it is at odds with the C++ goal of "leaving no room for a lower-level language".  You'd have to instrument your classes manually that you'd want to have that additional behavior.

Comment: Why don't you put the copy in the container and then modify the container's copy? Or, why don't you make a copy, edit the copy, then move the copy into the container?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat as you mentioned this first you might as well put it as an answer and i'll accept

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posting my comment as an answer:

---

I would pass the parameter by rvalue reference: `Obj&& obj`.

This lets you move the object into the container instead of copying it.

There's also an implication that an argument passed to this function shouldn't be used after the call, but the compiler won't enforce this.

Answer (score 0):

Delete the copy constructor and copy assignment if you always want this behavior.

```
class Obj
{
public:
    Obj(const Obj&) = delete;
    Obj& operator=(const Obj&) = delete;
    Obj(const Obj&&);
    Obj& operator=(const Obj&&);
    /* Possibly virtual if this is a base class in a hierarchy */
    ~Obj();

    // Rest of the stuff
};
```

However, this will disable copy semantics everywhere and you'll be forced to use move semantics instead just like `std::unique_ptr<T>`.

You should also refer to the [rule of 5](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three) to understand why I am explicitly declaring move constructor and assignment, and the destructor.

Answer (score 0):

Split your function:

```
void modifyObjectAndStore(Obj& obj)
{
    obj.a = 5;
    obj.b = 8;
    // there's state set here which isn't possible to set in the caller
    _container.takeCopy(obj);
    use(_container.back());
}

void use(const Obj& obj)
{
    
    // ...
}
```

Comment: This is what I did in the end, except I returned the object back as const from the modify function.